# D3.js transition bar chart when switching between data sources

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3.js to create a bar chart. I have several source CSV files that I switch between based on user input:

```
onclick="showFoo();"
onclick="showBar();"
```

Then:

```
function showFoo(){d3.csv("teams/foo.csv",type,update)}
function showBar(){d3.csv("teams/bar.csv",type,update)}

function update(error, data) {
x.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.category;}));
y.domain([0,1]);
chart.select(".x.axis").remove();
chart.append("g")
    .attr("class","x axis")
    .attr("transform","translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor","start")
    .attr("transform","rotate(-90)");
chart.selectAll(".bar").remove();
chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .attr("x",function(d){return x(d.category);})
    .attr("y",function(d){return y(d.value);})
    .attr("height",function(d){return height - y(d.value);})
    .attr("width",x.rangeBand());
};
```

I am using an ordinal scale for my x axis. The data files have different numbers of categories. What I want to do is animate the switch between the two data sources. Specifically, have the first bars drop down and disappear below the x axis, then have the new bars pop up from below. I'm a D3 noob and haven't been able to find an example of this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use transition for the animation

For removing:

```
chart.selectAll(".bar")
     .transition()
     .duration(300)
     .ease("exp")
     .attr("width", 0).remove()
```

For creating

```
chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .attr("x",function(d){return x(d.category);})
    .attr("y",function(d){return y(d.value);})
    .attr("height",function(d){return height - y(d.value);})
    .attr("width",x.rangeBand());
```